# GET PHP Variables in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, get, load, urlrequest

I have trawled the web and used multiple examples but not getting anywhere at all!

I want to URLRequest (LOAD) a PHP file with the get parameters that look like this "q1a=test"

Current script gives me an UNDEFINED error:

```
var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest("loadme.php");  
request.method=URLRequestMethod.GET;  

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();  
loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;  
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);  
loader.load(request);  

function completeHandler(evt:Event) {  

  displaydata.text = "This "+evt.target.data.q1a;

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to load a file (variables) from that URL or you are trying to send them?

Comment: I am trying to load it: http://solourl.com/for_matt/loadme.php - baring in mind the SWF is in the same file.

Comment: Fixed!! Code works, it was my php file causing errors (doctypes etc)